# cant install ubuntu from legacy and uefi

Tags: 14.04

I tried installing ubuntu at I m getting error message when. Choose my usb naming sandisk 8 gb error was using us english keyboard with us english codepage 437 then I change.
 Legacy to uefi mode then I choose external usb I got 4 options 
1try ubuntu 
2install ubuntu
3 oem install 
4 check disc for errors at firt it install propery but 2 nd time when I was choosing install ubuntu by mistake I chose check disc error after that 
it restart and showing media test failure and after 2 seconds message appeared boot device not found hard disk 3f0 
f2 system diagnostice again I tried with that uefi external usb it install ubuntu but when after installing it says go restart It again shows media failure 
and boot device not found etc etc

Comment: Do you have any other OS installed?

Comment: No when I install it always shows using us english keyboard with us english codepage 437